# Pigeonhole solution for product of elements of a group $H$ closed under ordinary multiplication

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics, group-theory, pigeonhole-principle

Let $H$ be a finite group with an identity element. Suppose that $\#H = n$ and $(a_1,\ldots,a_n)\in H^n= H\times\cdots \times H$ ($n$ times). It is to prove there exists $p$,$q$ with $0 \leq p<q\leq n$ such that the products $a_1a_2\cdots a_p$ $=$ $a_1a_2\cdots a_p\cdots a_q$.

How to apply Pigeonhole problem to it? Will the element and their respective inverses form a pair and hence a hole eg. $(a_1,a_1^{-1}),(a_2,a_2^{-1})\cdots(a_r,a_p^{-1})$ and try to fit $n$ pigeons that is $(a_1,\ldots ,a_n)$ into those holes?

Comment: Hint: Let $x_i = a_1a_2...a_i$. There are two cases either $x_p = x_q$ for some $1 \leq p < q \leq n$ or not. For the first case you should be able to conclude immediately, while for the second you need to use the pigeon hole principle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in Nex's hint, let $x_i = a_1a_2\dots a_i$, with $0 \leq i \leq n$ (where $x_0$ is simply the identity element). Since the index $i$ can assume $n+1$ values and $H$ has order $n$, for at least one pair of distinct indices $0 \leq p < q \leq n$ it must be that $x_p = x_q$ (for otherwise, one would have $n+1$ distinct elements in $H$).

Comment: Just to confirm I got this correct: Pigeons :: $x_{0}=e , x_{1}=a_{1} , x_{2} = a_{1}a_{2} , \cdots ,x_{n}= a_{1}a_{2}\cdots a_{n}$  and the holes are the distinct values which DOES NOT make the product identity :: $x_{1}=a_{1},x_{2}=a_{1}a_{2}\cdots x_{n}= a_{1}a_{2}\cdots a_{n}$ plz suggest

Comment: Pigeons are the $x_i$, holes are (the values of) the elements of $H$. Each pigeon corresponds to a hole; there are $n+1$ pigeons and $n$ holes.

Comment: so u mean $x_{i}$ corresponds to $a_{i}$ ...can we say there is a bijective mapping between sets of $x_{i}$ to the sets of $a_{i}$ ... and the mapping   is $f:x->a s.t. x_{i} = \prod a_{k}$

Comment: I am not sure I understand you. For each $i=0,1,\dots,n$ ***define***

$$x_i = \prod_{m=1}^ia_m$$

where $x_0$ is the empty product, the identity element.

Comment: yaaa i meant that